# Rendering partial in bootstrap popover rails 5 app?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-popover, html-safe

I'm having a problem rendering a partial in a bootstrap popover in my rails app.

The partial is always rendered as a plain text( showing all the HTML tags etc).

this is the code from the index.html.erb

```
<span class="has-popover"
      style="cursor:pointer;"
      data-toggle="popover"
      data-trigger="hover"
      data-container="body"
      data-placement="right"
      title="Lorem Ipsum"
      data-content= "<%= render :partial => 'envs/e1' %>" >
      <i class="fa fa-question-circle "  aria-hidden="true"></i>
</span>
```

In the `app.js` I have this snippet

```
$(".has-popover").popover({
    html : true
});
```

and this is the `_e1.html.erb` partial in the `envs` folder

```
<h2>Mauris euismod sollicitudin?</h2>

<p>Morbi sit amet tellus pellentesque, maximus eros a, aliquam nunc. Vivamus velit velit, vestibulum at eros eu, iaculis hendrerit tortor. Morbi ullamcorper purus at ornare ullamcorper. </p>

<br>

<p>Morbi sit amet tellus pellentesque, maximus eros a, aliquam nunc. Vivamus velit velit, vestibulum at eros eu, iaculis hendrerit tortor. Morbi ullamcorper purus at ornare ullamcorper. </p>
```

I have wrapped `"<%= render :partial => 'envs/e1' %>"` this line in both `raw()` and `html_safe` without any luck.

*** ADDED EXAMPLES ***
below are examples on how I've been using `html_safe`and `raw` in the snipped

`data-content= raw("<%= render :partial => 'envs/e1' %>")`  - text appears the "right" way but outsite the popover.

`data-content= "<%= raw(render :partial => 'envs/e1') %>" >` - text appears as plain-text

`data-content= "<%= render :partial => raw('envs/e1') %>" >` - text appears as plain-text

`data-content= "<%= render :partial => 'envs/e1' %>".html_safe`- text appears as plain-text

`data-content= "<%= render :partial => 'envs/e1'.html_safe %>"` - text appears as plain-text

there must be some way to have the partial styled inside the popover??
Or am I doing this all wrong?

please advise me
thanks in advance.

Comment: The naming convention of partial like start with underscore e.g `_e1.html.erb` then render like this `envs/e1`. however, have you seeing any error in console or log?

Comment: @fool-dev since the partial IS being rendered as plain-text, I don't think there is an issue with finding the partial template.

Comment: Can you modify your question to add an example of *how* you used `raw` and `html_safe`?

Comment: @SteveH. I've added examples of how I'm using `raw`and `html_safe`

Comment: Try: 
    data-content= "<%= render :partial 'envs/e1' %>"

Comment: @ChrisBuck it don't work, gives syntax error

Comment: Interesting. Try double (") quotes for the inner quotes as well. so: "<%= render :partial "envs/e1" %>"
(That's what the example I was reading had, which I've now misplaced, sorry.)

Comment: @ChrisBuck thats still gives the error `/index.html.erb:54: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting ')'`

Comment: Are you using `:partial` for any specific reason? Rendering a partial can be done by using `<%= render 'envs/e1' %>`.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that you have to enable `data-html = "true"` in your popover span.
 At least it worked at my machine.

So it would be written like:

```
<span class="has-popover"
  style="cursor:pointer;"
  data-toggle="popover"
  data-trigger="hover"
  data-html="true" <!-- This is what you have to add to the code -->
  data-container="body"
  data-placement="right"
  title="Lorem Ipsum"
  data-content= "<%= render :partial => 'envs/e1' %>" >
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, Bootstrap popovers don't accept html entered into them by automatically inheriting the option: `data-html="false"` you need to add and change it to `true`.

If you want to read more about what options you can pass through to bootstrap popovers, check out [this section of their API](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#popovers-options) and you can review what you can potentially do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Your Bootstrap markup and JS look fine, so the issue is almost certainly that your view is outputting escaped HTML rather than the markup that you need.

Your attempts with `html_safe` are very close and definitely on the right track, but the lack of brackets means that it's not quite doing what you think. Try this instead:

```
data-content="<%= render(partial: 'envs/e1').html_safe %>"
```

Note that the `html_safe` is applied to the output of `render`, and the outer quotes are retained in the HTML and not interpreted by Rails.